# Как указать задачу copy для watch отдельную?

Tags: grunt

watch следит за изменениями и запускает задачу copy, 
а мне нужно не все задачи copy запускать, а только отдельную specialCopy 
tasks: ['copy'], 
tasks: ['copy.specialCopy'],

```
   copy: {
      main: {
        files: [{
          cwd: 'C:/inetpub/myApp/',
          expand: true,
          src: ['./**'],
          dest: 'C:/inetpub/myApp/rrr2'
        }, {
          cwd: 'C:/inetpub/myApp/',
          expand: true,
          src: ['**'],
          dest: 'C:/inetpub/myApp/rrr3'
        }],
      },
       specialCopy: {
        files: [{
          cwd: 'C:/inetpub/myApp/',
          expand: true,
          src: ['./**'],
          dest: 'C:/inetpub/myApp/rrr2'
        }],
      }
}, 
     watch: {
      scripts: {
        files: [
          'myApp/js/**',
        ],
        tasks: ['copy.specialCopy'], // specialCopy
        options: {
          spawn: false,
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tasks: ['copy:specialCopy']
```

Подробнее в [документации](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task)